# C++20 support in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl, c++20, fmt

I'm wanting to use `std::format` but Visual Studio says the `std` namespace has no member `format`.

It appears this is new for C++20. Is there a way to make it available?

Comment: Are you asking if you can *make* a piece of code implement something that it doesn't implement?

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Huh? I want to use `std::format`.

Comment: @idclev463035818: Version of what? I'm using Visual Studio 16.5.1.

Comment: @JonathanWood: Yes, and `std::format` is, or would be, provided by the C++ standard library provided by your C++ implementation. Which is a piece of code. A piece of code that doesn't implement `std::format`. So you're asking how to make it implement something it doesn't implement.

Comment: Have you set your project options to use the 'latest' (preview) C++ standard?

Comment: @NicolBolas: No, that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: @AdrianMole: I'm not sure how to do that, but am not sure I want to use preview code. Are you saying Visual Studio does not yet have full support for C++20?

Comment: @JonathanWood: But that's what your question boils down to, whether you recognize it or not. If your car doesn't support flying, you can't *make it* support flying.

Comment: @JonathanWood: Since you're not getting the hint, I'll spell it out for you: Visual Studio (nor [any other C++ standard library implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) ) does not yet support `std::format`.

Comment: @S.S.Anne: Is there an option setting somewhere for that? I couldn't find it. Also, when you say the latest version, do you mean later than 16.5.1? Looks like 16.5.4 is the latest.

Comment: @JonathanWood In project properties -> C/C++ -> Language ... select "Use Latest (Preview) Draft Standard" However, I just tried (VS 16.5.4) and it doesn't have the `<format>` header - so I think you're out of luck.

Comment: @JonathanWood Nope, sorry. std::format is not implemented yet. Actually, no standard library implements it.

Comment: fyi Microsoft C++ language conformance table - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019

Comment: As you're using Visual Studio: the MFC/ATL `CString` has a `Format` member, and conversion between `CString` and `std::string` (or `std::wstring`) is relatively trivial.

Comment: @AdrianMole: I'm an old-time MFC programmer so this was my first thought. I feel like I should be using newer technologies but it's often much easier to stick with what works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of the time of writing, no C++ standard library implements `std::format`.

There are various implementations available on the web, like https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt (presumably the original source of the proposal, in `fmt::`) and https://github.com/mknejp/std-format (which puts everything in `std::experimental::`).

I wouldn't recommend pulling these into `std`. If I had to deal with something like this, the solution I would go for would be:

- Add a `#define <some-unique-name>_format <wherever>::format` and then use `<some-unique-name>_format`.
- Then, once you get `std::format` support, search-and-replace `<some-unique-name>_format` with `std::format` and toss the `#define`.

It uses macros, but in the long run it's better than having unqualified `format` everywhere.

Comment: @TemplateRex What would you suggest doing? A namespace alias can't pull into `std`; otherwise, it would be undefined behavior

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 v16.10 has just added `std::format`!

Answer (score 5):

You can use [fmt](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html) as a sort of polyfill. It's not identical but has a significant feature overlap. So if you're careful about how you use it you can swap it out for `<format>` once support is there.

```
#include <string>
#include <version>
#ifndef __cpp_lib_format
#include <fmt/core.h>
using fmt::format;
#else
#include <format>
using std::format;
#endif

int main()
{
    std::string a = format("test {}",43);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As of the release of Visual Studio 2019 version 16.10 (released May 25th 2021) support was added for `std::format`. Just compile with `/std:c++latest`.