# C++ std:format not available in VS2022 /std:c++latest

Tags: c++, format, c++20, c++-chrono, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to use C++ std::format in Visual Studio 2022.

I've selected C++ Language Standard: "Preview - Features from the Latest C++ Working Draft (/std:c++latest)" after initially trying "ISO C++20 Standard (/std:c++20)"

The post below seems to indicate that selecting the Preview standard should work, but I don't have enough status to comment on that post directly.
[C++20 support in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61561306/c20-support-in-visual-studio)

Should std::format work in VS2022 with the #include  statement?

Comment: Please show your code (in form of a [mcve]) and the exact errors you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should std::format work in VS2022 with the #include statement?

Yes, but it currently only works in `/std:c++latest` (Preview) mode which you can set in `Project\Properties\Configuration\Properties\C++ Language Standard`.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jY3dafYh5)

Comment: Thanks for you code snippet and explanation.  I was able to get your demo code working and my system recognizes the std::format code when creating a new example.

One complication I currently have is that I have some legacy code VS2019 C++ that does not recognize std::format even when /std:c++latest (Preview) is selected.  I'll dig into this more to see why the demo code works but my legacy code does not.

Comment: I found that I was targeting Release, but I was changing the C++ version in Debug.  Changing the release C++ version solved the initial issue.  Thanks again

Comment: @jeff28273 Oh, great. I've made that mistake myself a couple of times :-) You're welcome!